# Unable to read document OfficeImportErrorDomain error 912 on generaring .xlsx file using openXml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I am using OpenXMl to generate Excel file (.xlsx). I am able to open generated file (.xlsx) on my computer but I can not open it on my Ipad.  It is not password protected even, but I do get the 912 error.

This is my C# code

```
string fileName = "Report.xlsx";          
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";// "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"; //"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml" '"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" '"application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
```

Any Help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: ipad browser shows error when i open .xlsx file generated using OpenXml, i checked browser can open other .xlsx file or ms doc , is there any restriction by OpenXMl?  i also set mimetype but not seem to be working:(

Comment: looks like the OpenXml generated xlsx file is not valid. simply use another program to open that file, like Excel on windows. looks like you need to lodge this as bug on OpenXml support site.

Comment: See if this helps. It's something to do with the internal /xl/ folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929054/openxml-spreadsheet-created-in-net-wont-open-in-ipad

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to generate the .xlsx file you need with a third-pard component, such as ClosedXML?

We used it recently, it takes 15 mins to implement: maybe you can give it a try.
If the issue is related to not-perfectly compliance with the OpenXml format, maybe ClosedXml can do better...

[Github](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)
(moved from [Codeplex](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/))